# Using grep to search for instances of a string in all files within a directory, using PHP bash script

Tags: php, linux, grep

I am writing a PHP command line script, and I'm wondering if any grep experts can help me to come up with a command to do the following:

For all files ending in .java in the current directory ($curDir), search within the file for any instance of $str, and return an indicator whether any instance has been found or not.

I've tried piecing together a grep command from various bits found on the internet but, having not really used grep before, its a bit difficult to piece together. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "PHP bash script," they're quite different. Are you calling a bash script from within a PHP script, or just PHP? Are you trying to capture the output of the grep from within PHP?

Comment: The answers you're getting are for bash - please clarify and remove php tags if this is what you want.

Comment: My apologies, I was a little confused. It is a php script, not a bash script.

Comment: Actually, the response I gave was exactly what was requested - execute a bash line from within php. That is a perfectly acceptable thing to request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
exec("grep '$str' *.java", $output_array);
```

Use `-l` if you want it to just output the file names.  Other grep options can be found here:
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep

Depending on what `$str` is you may need to pass it through: `escapeshellarg()`:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Answer (score 0):

Grep is well suited to that task.

```
grep -rl '$str' .
```

That command will report file names of files that match your string.  It will only report each file name once but that seems to be what you want.  The option "-r" says to recursively traverse the file system and the option "-l" says to just report file that contain a match.  You may also want to check out the options "-H" and "-n" as I use them frequently.